# Project Advice: push ERP/SQL transaction data to Slack

Tags: python, sql, architecture, slack-api, epicorerp

I'm embarking on a software project, and I have a bit of an idea on how to attack it, but would really appreciate some general tips, advice or guidance on getting the task done. Project is as follows:

My company has an ERP (Enterprise Resource Planning) system that we use to record all our business activity (i.e. create purchase orders, receive shipments, create sales orders, manage inventory etc..). All this activity is data entry into the ERP system that gets stored in a SQL Server database.

I would like to push this activity to certain Slack channels via text messages.

For example, when the shipping department creates a 'receipt entry' (they receiving in a package) in the ERP system, then production team would get a text saying 'item X has been received in' in their Slack channel.

My current napkin sketch is this:

For a given business activity, create a function that executes a SQL query to return the most recent data entry.

Store this in my own external database.

Routinely execute these calls (Maybe create a Windows scheduler to execute a program that runs through all the functions every 30 minutes or so??), which will compare the data from the query to the data last saved in my external database.

If the same, do nothing. But if they're different:

Replace the data from my external database with this new data, then use Slacks API to post a message of this new data to Slack.

I'm not too certain about the mechanics of executing a program to check for new activity in the ERP system, and also uncertain about using a second database as a means of remembering what was sent to Slack previously. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!
Josh

Answer (score 2):

Epicor ERP has a powerful extension system built in.

I would create a Business Process Method (BPM) for ReceiptEntry.Update. This wouldn't check for added rows but more specifically where the Recieved flag has been changed to set. This will prevent you getting multiple notifications every time a user saves an incomplete record.

In the BPM you can reference external assemblies and call the Slack APIs from there.

I **strongly** recommend you avoid trying to do this at the database level instead of the application level. The schema can change and it is much harder to maintain the system if someone has been adding code to the database. If it isn't done carefully it can break the Data Model Regeneration in the Epicor Administration Console and prevent you from adding UD fields or upgrading your database.

Comment: Ah great insight! I haven't explored BPM's much yet. Sounds like I need to investigate BPM's and external assemblies a bit more, do you know of any good resources to learn more about this?

Comment: The BPMs are Epicor specific so most of the good resources are on epicweb.epicor.com but you will need an account to get into this.

Answer (score 1):

You should investigate Triggers, and Queues.  You can add triggers to your SQL Server tables that drop messages on Queues, then have a service at the other end of the queue writing messages to Slack API.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/555070

Comment: Interesting stuff, I'll look into them thanks. I don't have much control over the SQL Server structure or tables.. I can essentially just read from them. But despite that maybe I can make use of Triggers. Queues are a great idea, wonder if I can store the information after the program runs

Comment: Having a queue at the end makes a lot of sense, since Slack has a rate limit of 1 message per second (yes its that low). So you will need  a queue to store your message, while your service is sending them to Slack.